# how to make unity build folders share the same assets

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I have multiple Unity3d applications (projects). But the underlying scenes and assets are meant to be common across these different applications. Right now, I am having to manually copy the assets folder across the different projects before a build is taken.

How can I make my Unity project refer to a common assets folder (shared between more than one Unity project)?

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with symbolic links.

If you are using windows:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink

For example:

```sh
# mklink /d link target
mklink /d "C:\unity\mysharedfolder" "C:\unity\project1\linktosharedfolder"
```

Or on a Unix system:

```sh
man ln
```

For example:

```sh
ln -s ./mysharedfolder/ ./project/linktosharedfolder
```

Comment: Thank you. I assume this is possible for assets folder too. Right ?

Comment: I would change `on a Mac` to `on a Unix system` ... and @NRB this would go for any folder you wish, your OS doesn't care if it is a Unity project